# How to disable Twitter comments?

Tags: twitter

Some of the Twitter users whom I follow disabled reply feature. There is always a reply button but, when I post a message, it won't shown in expanded message.

To be more specific, a journalist posts a tweet. I and some other users reply to it and our tweets are shown in direct link of tweet, but after one minute, all replies are gone! Only the original tweet is left.

For example;

https://twitter.com/anadoluajansi/status/348005378539282432

How are they doing this? Is there any way for me to do the same?

Comment: I'm really curious about this too. This one seems a very common problem among twitter users...

Comment: In 2020 Twitter started letting users choose who can reply. There's a dropdown under your tweet where you can disable comments.